# Using find to locate files not owned by USER or GROUP

Tags: linux, bash, find

I need to find files and folders in CentOS 7 where they are either not owned by user or not owned by group.

I have 3 test directories:

```
root:root test1
root:group test2
user:root test3
```

I need to be able to find all 3 directories, so I can chown user:group, in one find command.

I've tried these:

```
find . ! -user user -or ! -group group
find . ! \( -user user -or -group group \)
```

But none of them work. Have I misunderstood something?

I've done some further testing, and by using the first example: `find . ! -user user -or ! -group group -print0` I can only get results from `test1` directory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**not (X or Y)** and **(not X or not Y)** are different things, negation is not a distributive operation. You indeed need parentheses there—as **-o** has a lower precedence than **-a** implied by the conjunction of primaries—, but also both predicates inside should be negated.

```
find . \( ! -user user -o ! -group group \) -exec chown user:group {} +
```